# How do I count the number of grouped rows/observations?

Tags: r

How do I count the number of grouped rows/observations?

I know this should be a simple question, but im having trouble figuring it out.

I am using the `flights` dataframe which has has year, month, day, and individual flights.

**I want to summarize/count the number of flights per day.**

What ‘i’ve tried….

```
flights %>% 
    group_by(year, month, day, flight) %>%
    summarize(n())
```

This gives the number of each flight

```
special_days2 <- flights %>%
    group_by(year, month, day) %>% 
    count(flight)
```

This gives me the same as using `summarize(n())`. But  I am confused. I grouped by year, month, day, and used count on flights, so it counts the number of unique observations within flight, correct?

Is there no way to count the number of flights, grouped by year, month, day?

```
flights %>% 
    group_by(year, month, day) %>%
    summarize(n())
```

This does give me the count per day, but it is not specific to the flights column. So i had to assume that the number of rows per day would correspond to the number of flights per day.

Is there no other way to ask the question myself, “how many flights per day?” using the flights column grouped by other columns? When I tried to use nrows() to count the number of rows,

```
special_days3 <- flights %>%
      group_by(year, month, day) %>% 
      nrow(flight)
```

^ this gave me an error,

and

```
special_days3 <- flights %>%
      group_by(year, month, day, flight) %>% 
      nrow()
```

Just gave me the total number of rows? I am confused because nrow seems to be the right command to use as it counts the number of rows but it did not work.

Thank you for your guidance!

---

Also on the topic of using summarize, count, and n()
My understanding is that summarize() houses select functions. How do you know which functions those are?  I know they are statistical functions and n(), but besides that?

Conversely,  some functions must be housed by summarize, like n(). Are there others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain why you get the output for each of your attempts:

```
flights %>% group_by(year, month, day, flight) %>% summarize(n())
```

Here you group by `year`, `month`, `day` (so far so good) **and** `flight` (`flight` is unique, that's why you are getting 'the number of each flight')

```
special_days2 <- flights %>% group_by(year, month, day) %>% count(flight)
```

Here you group by  `year`, `month`, `day` (again, so far so good) but then you **count** the unique values of `flight` which is unique, so you are getting the same output as above

```
flights %>% group_by(year, month, day) %>% summarize(n())
```

or even better:

```
flights %>% group_by(year, month, day) %>% summarize(N = n())
```

or

```
flights %>% group_by(year, month, day) %>% count()
```

gives you exactly what you want, i.e. your assumption 'that the number of rows per day would correspond to the number of flights per day' is correct.

Comment: okay great thank you. so I must make that assumption and make sure that assumption is correct in these cases.  That is good to know. I guess that is why it is important to understand the dataset as a whole, and think about how I want to handle NA values (if they exist). Im just trying to think of exceptions to when that assumption might be dangerous to make too readily. Thank you!

Comment: You **always** have to know what the data represents! In most cases rows refer to unique observations, but there are many, many exceptions.